# How to use refs when parent and child component are both functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-ref

I have two components, one being Parent and other one Child, both as functional components. In the parent component I have a submit button, which when invoked will call a function defined in the Child functional component (e.g. submitHandler()). By using the forwardRef() in child component I am unable to access the submitHandler() of child functional component. Any idea/help regarding how can i tackle this?

Comment: what you have done so far? show your code / add codesandbox or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `useImperativeHandle` hook.

for more info have a look at this post
[Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)